# Why does Control.ResetBindings() clear control's DataBindings?

Tags: c#, winforms

Code:

```
    ComboBox comboBox = new ComboBox();
    comboBox.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("SelectedItem", "", null));
    Debug.WriteLine($"Bindings count = {comboBox.DataBindings.Count}");
    comboBox.ResetBindings();
    Debug.WriteLine($"Bindings count = {comboBox.DataBindings.Count}");
```

Output:

```
Bindings count = 1 
Bindings count = 0
```

while [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.resetbindings?view=netframework-4.8) says "Causes a control bound to the BindingSource to reread all the items in the list and refresh their displayed values."

Comment: Unless I'm reading the reference source incorrectly (and it's very likely I could be - only glanced at it), it actually does look like it just clears the bindings... The MSDN docs seem inaccurate to me.

Comment: Hmm... This is what it really does in this source code... http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/WinForms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control@cs/1305376/Control@cs

Comment: @BrootsWaymb is right: [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,04947c17f3c11e65)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like MSDN is really inaccurate.
What really makes control update value from source is

```
comboBox.DataBindings[0].ReadValue();
```